# Is there any way to locate the current location of the user(browser other than mozilla and chrome)

Tags: internet-explorer, safari, geolocation, userlocation, currentlocation

My problem is to get the current latitude and longitude of the user.
I have tried Geoloaction API, it works fine in Mozilla(3.6-tested) and google chrome as well.
But fails in IE6,IE7(i tested only these versions) i think its because of the lack of HTML5 support ,But it fails in safari too. is there any way other than this? Is there any jquery library to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a job for [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) and the [Webshims Lib](http://afarkas.github.com/webshim/demos/index.html)...

The combination of these two javascript libraries provide you with implementations of HTML5 features (such as geolocation) in older browsers.  The Webshims Lib also provides a good [demo](http://afarkas.github.com/webshim/demos/demos/geolocation.html) of the geolocation API.